# How to show past console logs in Firebug?

Tags: logging, firebug

When I open Firebug console it is always empty and only new logs will appear. I would like to open Firebug and see say logs from the last 5 minutes -- is there a way to configure Firebug to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible in Firebug. I remember this was previously requested in [Firebug's issue tracker](https://github.com/firebug/firebug/issues), though I can't find the issue right now.

Anyway, [Firebug is officially discontinued](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2016/12/firebug-lives-on-in-firefox-devtools/) in favor of the [Firefox DevTools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools). And their [console](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Web_Console) shows also messages that were logged before the tools are opened.